# Does Firebase automatically encrypt passwords?

Tags: ios, firebase, firebase-authentication

Does Firebase automatically encrypt plain text passwords when creating a new user using the signUp() method? Also, does it automatically hash/encrypt plain text passwords with the signIn() method:

```
firebase.auth().createUserWithEmailAndPassword(email, password).catch(function(error) {}

...

firebase.auth().signInWithEmailAndPassword(email, password).catch(function(error) {}
```

Would `password` be plain text or already hashed?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You pass plain text, Firebase handles all the encryption.