# Flutter Firebase signInWithEmailAndPassword cryptography

Tags: flutter, firebase-authentication

I'm using Flutter + firebase auth to authenticate my users with email and password using this syntax:

```
void signIn({@required String email,@required String pass})   
FirebaseAuth.instance.signInWithEmailAndPassword(email: email, password: pass)...
```

The username and password are Strings, plain text

My question is, do I have to worry about password security? does the password string goes to the network encrypted?

Comment: Are you storing passwords somewhere? or using only for auth?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

All communication between the Firebase Authentication client and the backend servers happens over (HTTPS) connections that are end-to-end encrypted. So while the password may appear as plain text in the code, it cannot be seen by anyone checking the network traffic (unless the network is already compromised).

Also see:

- [Does Firebase automatically encrypt passwords?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58053508/does-firebase-automatically-encrypt-passwords)

Answer (score 0):

Don't Worry, Firebase already takes care of that for you.