# Is the Firebase sign in method signInWithEmailAndPassword(email, password); use in flutter sends the password hashed?

Tags: android, firebase, flutter, dart, firebase-authentication

```
final FirebaseAuth _firebaseAuth = FirebaseAuth.instance;
Future<String> signIn(String email, String password) async {
    AuthResult result = await _firebaseAuth.signInWithEmailAndPassword(
        email: email, password: password);
    FirebaseUser user = result.user;
    return user.uid;
  }
```

Does the **String password** passed to this function send it as original string or as a password hash?

Is the sent password as hash **OR** it is hashed at the backed ?

Comment: Please limit yourself to a single issue per question.  You might want to edit the question to remove the part about error handling and ask that separately.  You should make an attempt at explaining and solving the problem rather than just asking for general help.

Comment: Okay I'll take care next time. Thanks!

Comment: This seems a question for Firebase support, considerig the request is gonna be made HTTPS is probable is secure during the transaction and the the auth logic on the Firebase side does the remaining safety steps

Answer (score 1):

I think it is just passed the original string. Firebase Authentication uses an internally modified version of scrypt to hash account passwords. Even when an account is uploaded with a password using a different algorithm, Firebase Auth will rehash the password the first time that account successfully logs in. Accounts downloaded from Firebase Authentication will only ever contain a password hash if one for this version of scrypt is available, or contain an empty password hash otherwise.

Comment: Can you expand on "Accounts downloaded from Firebase"?

Comment: The auth:export command is used to export user accounts to JSON and CSV files. Please visit https://firebase.google.com/docs/cli/auth

Answer (score 1):

*firebaser here*

The password is sent from the client to the server in plain-text over an HTTPS/SSL connection.

Also see:

- [Does Firebase automatically encrypt passwords?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58053508/does-firebase-automatically-encrypt-passwords)
- [Flutter Firebase signInWithEmailAndPassword cryptography](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61409122/flutter-firebase-signinwithemailandpassword-cryptography)

Comment: Good to know. IMO this should be added to the docs to avoid unnecessary confusion/panic.