# should i encrypt the password field in a cloud firestore collection document?

Tags: firebase, flutter, dart

i've read many questions here in SO about Flutter/Firebase encryption and one the most straight forward answers i saw here is:

[Is the Firebase sign in method signInWithEmailAndPassword(email, password); use in flutter sends the password hashed?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63093675/is-the-firebase-sign-in-method-signinwithemailandpasswordemail-password-use)

my question is:

should i need to encrypt the password field of the user's document in cloud firestore users collections?!

passwords are stored in my collections like this:

[image: 1]

1. what should i do to prevent the staff members from seeing our users passwords in plain text like above?!
2. if i used the encrypt package from pub.dev..i can encypt the entered password in the input field by the user with encryption type "AES"..and then pass the encypted text to the cloud firestore users collection....what if a staff member has access to users firestore collection and saw this encrypted password string ?!
3. if both of the above questions are logically wrong...should i omit the password field completely from the cloud firestore users collection?!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

DO NOT SAVE ANY PLAINTEXT ABOUT PASSWORD.
You should **NEVER** save password without encrypt.
For you, for your user.

Comment: hi, thanks for your response...so now should i store the password field encypted?!...or should i remove the password field completely from cloud firestore users collections ?!

Comment: If you need to verify password, you need to save it. But save it as plaintext is unsafe. You may save it encrypted, and when you need to verify it, just encrypt what user input and check that encrypted string. If `encrypt(user_input) == what_you_saved`, thats correct.

Comment: It just called **password**, even you own the app, you have no access to read.  
 Zackburg don't know your facebook password, and he will never known. He only know your `encrypt(password)`.

Comment: Alright..thanks for your responses...much appreciated :)